# Access SessionVar from LiftSession.onShutdownSession listener

Tags: scala, lift

I have a SessionVar defined somwhere in my code:

```
object User extends SessionVar[Option[User]]
```

An an object which lives apart from sessions and requests.

```
object StatisticMonitor extends LiftActor{

    LiftSession.onAboutToShutdownSession::= onSessionShutdown

    def onSessionShutdown(targetSession: LiftSession) {
        //TODO: how to find User for session targetSession 
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is it true that inside `onSessionShutdown` `User` is bound to `targetSession` (i.e. by calling `User.is` I'll get the user which is shutting down).
2. Is there a way to access any `SessionVar` having `LiftSession` instance. (e.g. I have array of LiftSessions and I want to iterate over all session variables)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a handler to `onAboutToShutdownSession` will be called whenever any session expires, not just the current session which is bound to the `SessionVar`. If you are only concerned with the session bound to `SessionVar`, you probably want to override the [`onShutdown(session:CleanUpParam)`](http://liftweb.net/api/25/api/#net.liftweb.http.SessionVar) method on `SessionVar` instead.

I'm not sure exactly what you want to accomplish with point two, but I don't believe you can get access to the underlying `LiftSession` from the `SessionVar`.

Comment: `SessionVar` defines `CleanUpParam` as `CleanUpParam = LiftSession`. So I have `onShutdown(session:LiftSession)` again. And I have to extract SessionVar value which is bound to the `session`. 
I need something like `session.get(User)` to extract `User` session var from `session`.

Comment: Yes, except that since the `onShutdown` method exists within the `SessionVar`, you should be able to reference any methods on the expiring object with `this`.